# If an area is the same as another area

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a 5x5 flat area with different colors of clay on it in a certain shape, and on another 5x5 flat area, a player has to recreate that shape exactly. Is there a way to test if the two areas are the same, or will I have to do a testfor command for each individual block space? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`/testforblocks`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblocks) command allows you to check whether or not two areas are equal.

```
/testforblocks <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <x> <y> <z> [all|masked]
```

Example, checking if the area between 0,64,0 and 4,64,4 is the same as 100,64,100 to 104,64,104:

```
/testforblocks 0 64 0 4 64 4 100 64 100
```

Comment: Wonderful!! TY!